# Vector fields on $S^{4n-1}$ spheres

Tags: manifolds, tangent-bundle

I need to prove that there exists 3 independent vector fields on spheres of dimension 4n-1. I decided to try induction on n. The case $S^{3}$ was covered in 2 or 3 chapters back but i have no idea or intuition on how to construct 3 vector fields 4 dimensions up. Where do i even start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have $\mathbb{R}^4 \cong \mathbb{H}$, with $\mathbb{H}$ being the quaternions, you have $S^{4n - 1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{4n} \cong \mathbb{H}^n$.

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed!